# status code: 400, headers in afnetworking3.0 in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, afnetworking-2, afnetworking-3

[image: error here] 
This is screen shot from postman client .that api is working what is issue in my code how to set response and request .
i am making a post request in objective c using the AFNetworking 3.0  but request response bad request (400)
this is the errors

```
{ status code: 400, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = private;
    "Content-Length" = 1647;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html";
    Date = "Sat, 09 Apr 2016 15:49:32 GMT";
    Server = "Microsoft-IIS/7.5";
    "X-AspNet-Version" = "4.0.30319";
    "X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";
} }, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://mytesturl_Json.svc/ValidateLoginService, com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data=<efbbbf3c 3f786d6c
```

this the code to make a post request

```
 AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc]initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

 manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
 manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];

    [manager POST:@"http://mytesturl_Json.svc/ValidateLoginService" parameters:inputs progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {

        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);

    } failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

    }];
```

i tried like this also

```
-(void)postdata
{
    NSError *error;

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://virtuzo.in/AhprepaidTestService/AhprepaidAPI_Json.svc/ValidateLoginService"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                       timeoutInterval:60.0];

    [request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSDictionary *mapData = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: @"admin", @"UserName",
                             @"1234", @"Pwd",
                             nil];
    NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:mapData options:0 error:&error];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];


    NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request    completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"reponse==%@",response);
        NSLog(@"error==%@",error);


    }];

    [postDataTask resume];

}
```

**still i am getting same error**

```
reponse==<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7f9baa433990> { URL: http://virtuzo.in/AhprepaidTestService/AhprepaidAPI_Json.svc/ValidateLoginService } { status code: 400, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = private;
    "Content-Length" = 1647;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html";
    Date = "Thu, 14 Apr 2016 02:57:21 GMT";
    Server = "Microsoft-IIS/7.5";
    "X-AspNet-Version" = "4.0.30319";
    "X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";
} }
2016-04-14 08:27:22.833 Ahprepaid[79163:1281702] error==(null)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try different response serializer. What is the response format? is it string or is it in json format or else? according to that set response serializer. You can check your response in different tool like advance rest client, postman or you can ask to person who made api or web service..!

Update :

```
Update :

NSError *error;

 NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
  NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"[JSON SERVER"];
  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                  cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                           timeoutInterval:60.0];

 [request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
 [request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

 [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
 NSDictionary *mapData = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: @"TEST   IOS", @"name",
             @"IOS TYPE", @"typemap",
             nil];
 NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:mapData options:0 error:&error];
 [request setHTTPBody:postData];


  NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request    completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

  }];

  [postDataTask resume];
```

Try something like this. This is native way without afnetworking. You will et data as response in your completion handler. If your response is string then convert that data to string. if response in json format then conver that data in json in completion handler block. example of conversion ,

```
 //data to string
  NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

 /data to json object
 NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:myNSData options:kNilOptions error:&error]; // here two posibilitiew NSArray or NSDictionary (Try both ot you can use id)
```

Hope this will solve your problem..:)

**Update 2 :**

```
NSString *urlString2 = @"http://virtuzo.in/AhprepaidTestService/AhprepaidAPI_Json.svc/ValidateLoginService?UserName=admin&Pwd=1234";



NSURL *myUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString2];





NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:myUrl];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];


 NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];


[[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {


    NSString *str = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"str is %@",str);




}]resume];
```

This is giving same response as postman. I have tried in my demo. I have just append parameters with url.

**Update 3 :**

You are getting xml String so, it's little complected to serialize.

1) Download [XML Parser](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/09/simple-xml-to-nsdictionary-converter/). derag and drop in your project. (when you build you will get error in this class. whenever you get error comment(//) this line in this class. it's because it havent used ARC).

updated code :

```
 NSString *urlString2 = @"http://virtuzo.in/AhprepaidTestService/AhprepaidAPI_Json.svc/ValidateLoginService?UserName=admin&Pwd=1234";



NSURL *myUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString2];





NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:myUrl];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];


 NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];


[[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {


    NSString *str = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"str is %@",str);




    NSError *parseError = nil;
    NSDictionary *xmlDictionary = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLString:str error:&parseError];
    NSLog(@" %@", xmlDictionary);

    NSString *myfinalString = [[xmlDictionary valueForKey:@"string"]valueForKey:@"text"];
    NSLog(@"string is %@",myfinalString);



    NSError *jsonError;
    NSData *objectData = [myfinalString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objectData
                                                         options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                           error:&jsonError];
    NSLog(@"json is : %@",json);

}]resume];
```

Comment: Hey i have updataed my answer. check it. hope this will help.

Comment: I have used what u said and posted code also with params and url .still getting same error

Comment: What is you get in data in completion handler? was your data nil? check the length of data by data.length. Second thing what is the error description from completion handler? you can chek by error.localizedDescription.

Comment: And what parameters are you sending and how ? tell me that also

Comment: NSDictionary *mapData = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: @"admin", @"UserName",
                             @"1234", @"Pwd",
                             nil]; this is params i am sending , and i have full code inn my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109113/discussion-between-jace-and-lion).

Comment: what is the response that you get in postman? and the url used in your question is real url? if yes then i am going to check by making demo?

Comment: yes its real url and its working in postman but not in code can you check in demo @Lion

Comment: yes its real url and its working in postman but not in code can you check in demo @Lion

Comment: I have updated my answer. try update 2 portion. it's working and giving same response as postman gives.

Comment: In this way i am getting response in string how to take in array or dictionry

Comment: Check my update in answer. it's working fine. :) hope that now you don't have query. ;)  It took one hour to complete your task.

Comment: still i have issue  my str    "{\"Response\" : [{\"Responsecode\" : \"0\" , \"Response\" : \"Success\"}] , \"Data\" : [{\"ID\":1,\"DistributorID\":1,\"RoleID\":0,\"UserName\":\"admin\",\"Password\":\"LEDdWe3AXsJy+ECechi3fQ==\",\"Fname\":\"AHPrepaid.Ltd\",\"Lname\":\"\",\"EmailID\":\"info@ahprepaid.com\",\"MobileNumber\":\"9711679656\",\"IsActive\":true,\"ActiveFromDtTm\":\"\\\/Date(1432105200000)\\\/\",\"ActiveTo

Comment: can you change ulr ValidateLoginService in place of this make  ValidateLoginService_IOS  then respose is normal but i am not able to make json from string

Comment: check last `NSLog` statement print json object. i.e. NSDictionary.

Comment: NSString *str = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"str is %@",str);
        
        // Convert to JSON object:
    
        NSError *jsonError;
        NSData *objectData = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objectData
                                                             options:0
                                                               error:&jsonError];
        NSLog(@"json is : %@",json);

Comment: str is "{\"Response\" : [{\"Responsecode\" : \"0\" , \"Response\" : \"Success\"}] , \"Data\" : [{\"ID\":1,\"DistributorID\":1,\"RoleID\":0,\"UserName\":\"admin\",\"Password\":\"LEDdWe3AXsJy+ECechi3fQ==\",\"Fname\":\"AHPrepaid.Ltd\",\"Lname\":\"\",\"EmailID\":\"info@ahprepaid.com\",\"MobileNumber\":\"9711679656\",\"IsActive\":true,\"ActiveFromDtTm\":\"\\\/Date(1432105200000)\\\/\",\"ActiveToDtTm\":\"\\\/Date(1440918000000)\\\/\",\"CreatedBy\":1,\"CreatedDtTm\"

Comment: If you chenage url then scenario will be different. but why are you changing url. keep old one as it is as we got solution for that

Comment: i requested to api they have changed now how to convert str to json object

Comment: NSError *jsonError;
        NSData *objectData = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objectData
                                                             options:0
                                                               error:&jsonError]; but getting json si nil

Comment: `id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];` Try this. It may work i think.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that web service response which you are getting is not actually JSON response. Check the response which you are getting and this will help your code work!

Comment: i am getting error in error block .how to check response

Comment: Sorry dude, by mistake i have updated your answer instead of mine :(